# Questions about the proof of generalized Poisson summation formula.

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory

The generalized Poisson summation formula is 
$$
\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma} f(\gamma) = \sum_{ \pi \in \widehat{\Gamma \backslash G}} \hat{f}(\pi),
$$
where $G$ is a locally compact Abelian group, $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of $G$, $f$ is some function on $G$, $\widehat{\Gamma \backslash G}$ is the set of all unitary character of $\Gamma \backslash G$,
$$
\hat{f}(\pi) = \int_G f(x)\pi^{-1}(x)dx
$$
is the Fourier transform. If $G=\mathbb{R}$, $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}$, then we obtain the usual Poisson summation formula.

The following is the proof of the generalized Poisson summation formula. Let 
$$
F(x)=\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma} f(\gamma x).
$$
Then we have Fourier expansion
$$
F(x) = \sum_{\pi \in \widehat{\Gamma \backslash G}} c(\pi)\pi(x),
$$
$c(\pi)$ are Fourier coefficients.

We have
$$
c(\pi) = \int_{\Gamma \backslash G} F(x)\pi^{-1}(x)dx \\
= \int_G f(x)\pi^{-1}(x)dx \\
= \hat{f}(\pi)
$$
Therefore 
$$
\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma}f(\gamma x) = F(x) = \sum_{\pi \in \widehat{\Gamma \backslash G}} \hat{f}(\pi)\pi(x).
$$
The generalized Poisson formula is proved.

My question is: how to prove the equality
$$
\int_{\Gamma \backslash G} F(x)\pi^{-1}(x)dx = \int_G f(x)\pi^{-1}(x)dx?
$$

I think that 
$$
\int_{\Gamma \backslash G} F(x)\pi^{-1}(x)dx \\
= \int_{\Gamma \backslash G} \sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma} f(\gamma x)\pi^{-1}(x) dx \\
= \int_{\Gamma \backslash G} \sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma} f( x)\pi^{-1}( \gamma^{-1} x) d(\gamma^{-1}x).
$$
Do we have $$
\int_{\Gamma \backslash G} \sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma} f( x)\pi^{-1}( \gamma^{-1} x) d(\gamma^{-1}x) = \int_{\Gamma \backslash G} \sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma} f( x)\pi^{-1}(   x) dx = \int_{\Gamma \backslash G}  f( x)\pi^{-1}(   x) dx ?
$$
Thank you very much.

Comment: How does $f(x)\pi^{-1}(\gamma^{-1}x)$ become $f(x)\pi^{-1}(x)$? You can't change the second term without altering the first as well, no? And then you'd end up back at $f(\gamma x)\pi^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: @anon, thank you very much. I think that $\pi$ is $\Gamma$-invariant.

Comment: @LJR do you have a reference for where this result is stated/ proved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assertion is correct, but you are missing two ingredients in the proof

1) The dual group of $\Gamma/G$ is the group of characters that map each element of $\Gamma$ to $1$.

2) It helps if you distinguish cosets [x] from group elements x. You need the fact that if $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$, then given Haar measures on $G$ and $H$ there exists a Haar measure on $H/G$ so that

$$ \int_{G}f(g)dg = \int_{H/G}\int_{H}f(gh)dhd[g].$$

In your case, $H = \Gamma$ and Haar measure on it is just counting measure.