# Citation for generalized poisson summation formula

Tags: number-theory, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups, poisson-summation-formula

I am wanting to cite the general Poisson summation formula for locally compact abelian groups (such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740681/questions-about-the-proof-of-generalized-poisson-summation-formula)). Does anyone know of a proper (preferably peer-reviewed) place where this is written down properly?

Comment: Found it in Deitmar and Echterhoff "Principles of Harmonic Analysis", Theorem 3.6.3.

Comment: You should convert your comment/resolution in an "answer" and "accept" it to close-the-case.